# is this sentence correct? : Will, will Will will Will Will's will?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I 'm really confused to understand this sentence:

- Will, will Will will Will Will's will?

does it mean "Will-1 is going to will the will of Will-1 to Will-2" right?

Comment: Will (a person), will (future tense helping verb) Will (a second person) will (bequeath) [to] Will (a third person) Will's (the second person) will (a document)?

Someone asked Will 1 directly if Will 2 plans to bequeath his own will, the document, to Will 3. [[Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/weird-sentences-2014-1%3famp)]

Comment: Yep, there're 3 people who have same name here, not 2 people. Understood. Thanks

Comment: *Will, will Will will Will Will's will?* Change a few names: Will, will John will [to] David Peter's will?

Comment: There would be lots of problems, both legal and practical, about an attempt to will one's own will to somebody. The only circumstances in which one could, perhaps, imagine a will to be willed is if it is a very old one, which is now valuable as a historical document, and has long ago lost its legal significance.

Comment: Does any of the people who voted to close this question seriously think that it is a proofreading question, or that it would be improved by some additional research? The real reason for closing it seems to be that the question poses a contrived puzzle, which is such that answering it would not illuminate anything about English language and usage; if so, it would have been helpful to everybody concerned to say so clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will (a person), will (future tense helping verb) Will (a second person) will (bequeath) [to] Will (a third person) Will's (the second person) will (a document)? Someone asked Will 1 directly if Will 2 plans to bequeath his own will, the document, to Will 3.

There are 3 people who have same name.
[More example from BI](https://www.businessinsider.com/weird-sentences-2014-1)